# C#, return focus to last handled window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have written a program in C# that creates a notification if certain things have changed on my computer. I have implemented it such that this notification occurs without getting focus. However, when I click by mouse on this notification, it activates and takes focus. I would like it to not do that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I mean I want to make it not clickable by any mouse button or if it 
was activated return focus to last handled window.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Note that you can click [edit] below your question to add details.

Comment: I have tried googling and methods which are on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e7fef568-2c0b-41eb-9785-304f84d03819/how-to-prevent-a-form-from-being-activatedgaining-focus?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

Try use the Focusable property to make it non-focusable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx

Comment: I should add 
<AdornerDecorator 
              x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
              Focusable="False" 
            />
in manifest file?

Comment: Its hard to help without seeing any code.

Are you sure its just not taking the focus off the control and putting the focus on say the main page? 

If you want to keep the focus on the last control save the last controls state and then when you click the non-focusable control put the focus back on the saved control.

Comment: There is a lot of code, and also i have 2 forms. 1 of them is always updating to show new notification.What do you mean " putting the focus on say the main page?"?
How can i save the last control, when my form is not active.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
    private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
            p.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
            return p;
        }
    }
```